# Can not remove an entity through EntityManager#remove()

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I am using JPA.
I have the following code:

```
@Entity
public class NucleoFamiliar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String nombre;

    private Date fechaCreacion;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ADMINISTRADOR", nullable = false)
    private Usuario administrador;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "INTEGRANTE_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USUARIO"))
    private List<Usuario> integrantes;

    getters, setters...
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class SampleBusiness {
    @EJB
    private INucleoFamiliarDao nucleoFamiliarDao;

    public void excute() {
        NucleoFamiliar n = nucleoFamiliarDao.find(58);
        nucleoFamiliarDao.remove(n);
    }
}

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Testing implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EJB
    SampleBusiness ejb;

    public void execute() {
        ejb.execute();
    }

}
```

and part of the log

```
01:29:50,609 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Hibernate: select nucleofami0_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR as ID_NUCLE1_11_0_, nucleofami0_.ID_ADMINISTRADOR as ID_ADMIN4_11_0_, nucleofami0_.FECHA_DE_CREACION as FECHA_DE2_11_0_, nucleofami0_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE3_11_0_, usuario1_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR1_14_1_, usuario1_.ACTIVO as ACTIVO2_14_1_, usuario1_.APELLIDO as APELLIDO3_14_1_, usuario1_.EMAIL as EMAIL4_14_1_, usuario1_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE5_14_1_, usuario1_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD6_14_1_, usuario1_.TELEFONO as TELEFONO7_14_1_ from NUCLEO_FAMILIAR nucleofami0_ inner join USUARIO usuario1_ on nucleofami0_.ID_ADMINISTRADOR=usuario1_.ID_USUARIO where nucleofami0_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR=?

01:29:50,623 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Hibernate: select integrante0_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR as ID_NUCLE1_8_0_, integrante0_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR2_8_0_, usuario1_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR1_14_1_, usuario1_.ACTIVO as ACTIVO2_14_1_, usuario1_.APELLIDO as APELLIDO3_14_1_, usuario1_.EMAIL as EMAIL4_14_1_, usuario1_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE5_14_1_, usuario1_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD6_14_1_, usuario1_.TELEFONO as TELEFONO7_14_1_ from INTEGRANTE_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR integrante0_ inner join USUARIO usuario1_ on integrante0_.ID_USUARIO=usuario1_.ID_USUARIO where integrante0_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR=?

01:29:50,629 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Hibernate: select gruposjaas0_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR2_7_0_, gruposjaas0_.ID_GRUPO_JAAS as ID_GRUPO1_7_0_, grupojaas1_.ID_GRUPO_JAAS as ID_GRUPO1_5_1_, grupojaas1_.DESCRIPCION as DESCRIPC2_5_1_, grupojaas1_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE3_5_1_ from INTEGRANTE_GRUPO_JAAS gruposjaas0_ inner join GRUPO_JAAS grupojaas1_ on gruposjaas0_.ID_GRUPO_JAAS=grupojaas1_.ID_GRUPO_JAAS where gruposjaas0_.ID_USUARIO=?

01:29:50,631 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Hibernate: select nucleosfam0_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR2_8_0_, nucleosfam0_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR as ID_NUCLE1_8_0_, nucleofami1_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR as ID_NUCLE1_11_1_, nucleofami1_.ID_ADMINISTRADOR as ID_ADMIN4_11_1_, nucleofami1_.FECHA_DE_CREACION as FECHA_DE2_11_1_, nucleofami1_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE3_11_1_, usuario2_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR1_14_2_, usuario2_.ACTIVO as ACTIVO2_14_2_, usuario2_.APELLIDO as APELLIDO3_14_2_, usuario2_.EMAIL as EMAIL4_14_2_, usuario2_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE5_14_2_, usuario2_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD6_14_2_, usuario2_.TELEFONO as TELEFONO7_14_2_ from INTEGRANTE_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR nucleosfam0_ inner join NUCLEO_FAMILIAR nucleofami1_ on nucleosfam0_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR=nucleofami1_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR inner join USUARIO usuario2_ on nucleofami1_.ID_ADMINISTRADOR=usuario2_.ID_USUARIO where nucleosfam0_.ID_USUARIO=?

01:29:50,638 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Hibernate: select gruposjaas0_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR2_7_0_, gruposjaas0_.ID_GRUPO_JAAS as ID_GRUPO1_7_0_, grupojaas1_.ID_GRUPO_JAAS as ID_GRUPO1_5_1_, grupojaas1_.DESCRIPCION as DESCRIPC2_5_1_, grupojaas1_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE3_5_1_ from INTEGRANTE_GRUPO_JAAS gruposjaas0_ inner join GRUPO_JAAS grupojaas1_ on gruposjaas0_.ID_GRUPO_JAAS=grupojaas1_.ID_GRUPO_JAAS where gruposjaas0_.ID_USUARIO=?

01:29:50,640 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Hibernate: select nucleosfam0_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR2_8_0_, nucleosfam0_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR as ID_NUCLE1_8_0_, nucleofami1_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR as ID_NUCLE1_11_1_, nucleofami1_.ID_ADMINISTRADOR as ID_ADMIN4_11_1_, nucleofami1_.FECHA_DE_CREACION as FECHA_DE2_11_1_, nucleofami1_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE3_11_1_, usuario2_.ID_USUARIO as ID_USUAR1_14_2_, usuario2_.ACTIVO as ACTIVO2_14_2_, usuario2_.APELLIDO as APELLIDO3_14_2_, usuario2_.EMAIL as EMAIL4_14_2_, usuario2_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE5_14_2_, usuario2_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD6_14_2_, usuario2_.TELEFONO as TELEFONO7_14_2_ from INTEGRANTE_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR nucleosfam0_ inner join NUCLEO_FAMILIAR nucleofami1_ on nucleosfam0_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR=nucleofami1_.ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR inner join USUARIO usuario2_ on nucleofami1_.ID_ADMINISTRADOR=usuario2_.ID_USUARIO where nucleosfam0_.ID_USUARIO=?

01:29:50,701 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Hibernate: update NUCLEO_FAMILIAR set ID_ADMINISTRADOR=?, FECHA_DE_CREACION=?, NOMBRE=? where ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR=?

01:29:50,705 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-16) SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
01:29:50,705 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-16) Column 'ID_ADMINISTRADOR' cannot be null
```

Why is trying to update `NUCLEO_FAMILIAR`:

```
update NUCLEO_FAMILIAR set ID_ADMINISTRADOR=?, FECHA_DE_CREACION=?, NOMBRE=? where ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR=?)?!!
```

That's the problem because it tries to set to null a foreign key.

Comment: Can you show us your Usuario entity?

Comment: The JPA provider should not need to null the administrador field to do the remove since that has the FK, hence deleting the row from NucleoFamiliar will remove the FK directly. What is it setting the other fields to? Where does the UPDATE call come from ? the em.remove() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `nullable=false` from your `JoinColumn`. A JoinColumn is set as non nullable by default and if you want to set a nullable `JoinColumn` use the attribute `optional`.